# Fulfilling vassals' ambitions gives no opinion bonus. Is this a bug?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Say you have a vassal or couriter who wants to get married, and you help him by arranging marriage but his opinion of you doesn't change. Is this a bug or not?

I'm on version 2.1.6

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find on paradox forums, yes. This is a bug. Although possibly it has been resolved, I was playing with the newest patch (2.2.1) and I saw a "Fulfilled Marriage Ambition" bonus again.